# Need some hints and clarification to Problem 9, Section 46 in Munkres Topology

Tags: general-topology

The problem is shown in the image below. I solved part (a) and part (b). For part (c), I know why the map $Q$ is continuous, but I need some hints about how to prove that $G$ is continuous. Besides, I am not sure why the image of the map $G$ lies in $C(X,Y)$ (in part (b)). This is true if $g$ is a continuous map. However, showing that $g$ is continuous is what I ultimately need to do in part (c), and if I don't know that the image of the map $G$ lies in $C(X,Y)$, I can't use Theorem 46.11 to say that "$g$ is continuous because $G$ is continuous". This seems to be a circular argument to me. It would be of great help if someone can explain these things clearly to me.

[image]

Comment: Two comments: 1) If you prove that $Q$ is continuous, it follows immediately that $G$ is also continuous, because $p$, being a quotient map, has the property that a composite $ap$ is continuous if and only if $a$ is continuous. 2) I agree with you about the issue you find about the second point. Munkres seems not to be very accurate on this: in the Definition just above Theorem 46.11 he defines a function $Z \to \mathcal{C}(X, Y)$ for every function $f:X \times Y \to Z$. This is not well-defined: we need at least $f$ to be continuous for every fixed $y \in Y$.

Comment: Well, in this case you could argue as follows: you consider $Q: A \to Y^X$. Since this is induced by a continuous map $X \times A \to Y$, the image of $Q$ must be contained in $\mathcal{C}(X, Y)$. Then you consider $G: B \to Y^X$. You prove that there is an equality $Q=G \circ p$. Since $p$ is surjective, you can conclude that the image of $G$ also lies in $\mathcal{C}(X, Y)$. This should settle the issue. Also, please remove the picture and write down the text of the exercise yourself.